# segmentation fault filing sleep function

Tags: c, linux, file-io

hi every one i am getting a problem. i am using a sleep function. i have file which i open after 5 sec read all data and display it. it run for few time the give segmentation fault i am not getting it why its happening.i think there is nothing wrong with the file of program other wise it must hot have run 
thanks
 kindly help me
here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
void retrive()
{
FILE *fs;
char ch;
const int size =26;
const int size1 =3;
const int size2 =6;
        char sourceip[size];char destip[size];char sourceport[size2];char destport[size2];
        char sessionstart[size];char sessionend[size];char payload[size2];char sessionnum[size2]; 
  while(-1)
{      
    fs = fopen ( "processpacketlib.txt","r" ) ;
        if ( fs == NULL )
        {
               puts ( "Cannot open source file" ) ;
               return 0;
        }
int j;
int cnt =0;
printf("no of entries %d" , (noofentries("processpacketlib.txt")+1)/3);

//while(cnt<(noofentries("processpacketlib.txt")/3))
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
///ch= fgetc(fs);
//while(ch!=EOF)
{
int i=0;
printf("j = %d" ,j);
ch= fgetc(fs);
sourceip[i]=ch;
i++;
while ( ch!='\t')
        {

ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;        
sourceip[i]=ch;
        i++;
         }
sourceip[--i]='\0';
 i=0;
//================================================

ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
destip[i]=ch;
i++;
while ( ch!='\t' )
        {

        ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
        destip[i]=ch;

i++;
         }

destip[--i]='\0';
i=0;
//=================================================

ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
sourceport[i]=ch;
//printf("eh %c",eh[0])   ;
i++;
while (ch!='\t')
{
ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
sourceport[i]=ch;
//printf("eh %c",eh[1])   ;
i++;
 }
sourceport[--i]='\0';
i=0;
//=================================================

ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
destport[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[0])   ;
i++;
while (ch!='\t')
{
ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
destport[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[1])   ;
i++;
 }
destport[--i]='\0';
i=0;
//===============================================

ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
payload[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[0])   ;
i++;
while (ch!='\t')
{
ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
payload[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[1])   ;
i++;
 }
payload[--i]='\0';
i=0;

//==================================================

//==================================================

ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
sessionnum[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[0])   ;
i++;
while (ch!='\t')
{
ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
sessionnum[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[1])   ;
i++;
 }
sessionnum[--i]='\0';
i=0;


//=================================================
ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
sessionstart[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[0])   ;
i++;
while (ch!='\n')
{
ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
sessionstart[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[1])   ;
i++;
 }
sessionstart[--i]='\0';
i=0;
//======================================================

ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
sessionend[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[0])   ;
i++;
while (ch!='\n')
{
ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
sessionend[i]=ch;
//printf("np %c",np[1])   ;
i++;
 }
sessionend[--i]='\0';

ch = fgetc ( fs ) ;
//----------------------------------------------------*/
csvwrite(sourceip,destip,sourceport,destport,sessionstart,sessionend,payload,sessionnum);

printf("\nsip %s" , sourceip);
printf("\n dip %s" , destip);
printf("\nsource  %s",sourceport);
printf("\ndest %s",destport);
printf("\nt pay  %s",payload);
printf("\nt hdr %s",sessionnum);
printf("\nsession strat %s",sessionstart);
printf("\nsession end %s",sessionend);

printf("\n");

cnt++;
}// while ends
fclose(fs);
sleep(1);
}// outer infinite while ends

}
//==================================================================================

void csvwrite(char sourceip[],char destip[],char sourceport[],char destport[],char sessionstart[],char sessionend[],char payload[],char sessionnum[])
 {int retvalue;
int pos=0;
   char snum[5];char sstime[20];char payload1[10000] ;
struct tm tm;
time_t t;
char s[25]="Sat Feb 19 12:53:39 2011";
if (strptime(sessionstart, "%A %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", &tm) != NULL)
tm.tm_isdst = -1;      
t = mktime(&tm);
//if (t != -1)
//printf("seconds since the Epoch: %ld\n", (long) t);
char filename[35];
sprintf(filename,"%s%s%s%s",sourceip,"_",destip,".csv");
printf("filename %s",filename);

   FILE *fe = fopen(filename,"a");

   struct stat st;
   stat(filename, &st);
   int fsize = st.st_size;
   printf("before file size %d\n\n\n" ,fsize);        
if(fsize==0)
 {
        char stringtime[15];
    fprintf(fe,"%s",sessionnum);
    fprintf(fe,"%s"," ");
        sprintf(stringtime,"%ld",(long)t);
    fprintf(fe,"%s",stringtime);
    fprintf(fe,"%s"," ");
    fprintf(fe,"%s",payload);
    fprintf(fe,"%s","\n");
        fclose(fe);
        struct stat st1;
        stat(filename, &st1);
        int fsize1 = st1.st_size; 
        printf("after file size %d\n\n\n" ,fsize1);
   }
//fclose(filenname);
else
 {
    int count =noofentries(filename);
    printf("count%d",count);
    int i=0;
    int k=0;
int len =0;

    FILE *f1 = fopen(filename,"r");
    //char snum[5];char sstime[20];char payload1[100000] ; int payloadentries=0;// change pasted below
while(k<count)
     {char snum[5];char sstime[20];char payload1[100000] ; int payloadentries=0;

          char ch;
      ch= fgetc(f1);
      pos++;
          len++;
          // printf("\nch = %c" ,ch);
          snum[i]=ch;
          i++;
        while (ch!=' ')
                {
                    ch = fgetc ( f1 ) ;
                pos++;
                len++;
                    snum[i]=ch;
                    //  printf("ch %c",ch)   ;
                    i++;
            }
                snum[--i]='\0';
                i=0;
//--------------------------------------------
                ch= fgetc(f1);
                pos++;
                len++;
                    // printf("\nch = %c" ,ch);
                    sstime[i]=ch;
                                i++;
              while (ch!=' ')
                     {
                    ch = fgetc ( f1 ) ;
                pos++;
                len++;
                    sstime[i]=ch;
                    //  printf("ch %c",ch)   ;
                                i++;
                    }
                    sstime[--i]='\0';
                    i=0;
//---------------------------------------------
                    ch= fgetc(f1);
                pos++;
                len++;
                    // printf("\nch = %c" ,ch);
                payload1[i]=ch;
                    i++;
         while (ch!='\n')
                   {
                    ch = fgetc ( f1) ;
                pos++;
                len++;
                    payload1[i]=ch;
                    //  printf("ch %c",ch)   ;
                    i++;
                if(ch==' ')
                      {
                     payloadentries++;
                                      }

                  }
                payload1[--i]='\0';
                i=0;
                printf("\nsnum %s" ,snum);

                printf("\nsstime %s" ,sstime);

                printf("\npayload %s" ,payload1);

//  retvalue=addpayload(sourceip,destip,sourceport,destport,t,payload,sessionnum,snum,sstime,payload1,payloadentries+1,pos,count,filename);
//printf("rettttttttttvalue %d" ,retvalue);
        if ((retvalue==-2)||(retvalue==-1))
        {
printf("\n\nBREAK\n\n ");
         break;
        }
           k++;

   }//while end
           fclose(f1);
 } //else end
}// function end
//====================================================================================
```

Comment: If you show us some code, we can perhaps help you.

Comment: sir code is quite lenghty should i paste it ?? thanks

Comment: Much code is better than no code, and advanced users can edit your question to leave only important code.

Comment: Even better is a minimal test case that reproduces your problem.  This serves 2 purposes: It saves us from having to sift through 5000 lines of irrelevant code, and it shows that you've taken basic steps to try to solve the problem yourself before pawning off an entire novel on other people.

Comment: sir the code run well for some time thean same code give error . i am stuck dont where is the problem thanks

Comment: Ditto what Sdaz MacSkibbons said. I doubt anyone will want to wade through this mess to find the one bug you're asking about. Having skimmed it, I will suggest you check your looping code and make sure it doesn't run off the end of your data.

Comment: Try to run the program in a debugger. This should tell you *in which line* the segfault happens, which would be useful to know.

Comment: ok thanks kindly tell me that is it possible that same function will run at an intervel of 30 sec ,run for some time and give error which was previously not given  ? thanks

Comment: @schnaader : you regretting asking to see the code? ;)

Comment: @Mitch: Actually, not at all. Of course it's much code, it's a mess and the error could be anywhere, but we have something to talk about and can give better hints to solve the problem (like Vamana's and sth's comments).

Comment: @randy: Don't make the mistake of assuming that because your program starts up, and may even appear to "work" properly for some time, that it's therefore 100% right and correct. You can have code errors working with memory that cause symptoms only randomly.

Comment: I think in your void csvwrite() function, after the 'if' clause you commented a line saying 'fclose(filenname)', uncomment this line and check if it helps.

Comment: ok gkt sir thanks for concern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `else` branch of the `if(fsize==0)` conditional in `csvwrite()` does not `fclose(fe)`.  There is a limit on the number of files that can be opened by any one process at once; if you call this enough times, you'll hit the limit, and the next `fopen()` will return `NULL` (and `errno` will be set to `EMFILE` - "Too many open files").

That may or may not be the problem, so here's some more general advice:

1. Use a debugger.  If you don't know how, you should learn!  For example:

   ```
   $ cat test.c
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       int a = 123, b, c;
       int *p = &a;
       int *q = NULL;

       b = *p;
       c = *q;
       printf("%d %d\n", b, c);
       return 0;
   }
   $ gcc -Wall -o test test.c
   $ ./test
   Segmentation fault
   $
   ```

   Not very helpful.  But compile with `-g` and run it with `gdb`:

   ```
   $ gcc -g -Wall -o test test.c
   $ gdb ./test
   GNU gdb 6.8-debian
   Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
   and "show warranty" for details.
   This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu"...
   (gdb) run
   Starting program: /tmp/test
   ```

   ...and it will reveal the line where it fails:

   ```
   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   0x080483d4 in main () at test.c:10
   10        c = *q;
   (gdb) quit
   The program is running.  Exit anyway? (y or n) y
   $
   ```
2. Compile with warnings enabled (as I have done above with the `-Wall` flag).  The compiler is capable of spotting quite a lot of silly things, but you have to ask it.
3. Try indenting the code sensibly.  Readable code is easier to debug.
4. Remember to check return values.  `fopen()` in particular can fail for any number of reasons which are unrelated to your program.
5. Don't write vast amounts of practically identical code.  If you have to do the same job more than once, consider factoring it out into a separate function.

Comment: thank u so so much mathew sir u are a real helper i will definatly follow your advice thanks