# error after running for few minutes

Tags: c, linux

kindly tell me that is it possible that i run a program at an intervel of 30 sec ,run for some time and give error which was previously not given ? thanks
how to stop this

if my question is wrong kindly dont vote me down
just tell me my intention is not to hurt any one nor ask stupid question as i really appreciate you guys
thanks

Comment: This seems to be a cut-down version of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210735/segmentation-fault-filing-sleep-function

Comment: yes sir kindly answer me if you know and understands my problem. thank u

Comment: you mean like I did a few minutes ago....?

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice; it will avail you naught. Please do boil down the troublesome code to a minimal test case, verify that it does not work and you can't figure it out yourself, and use copy/paste to post it. And please don't post a useless vague question and then ask us not to vote it down. That's what voting down is _for_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just because your program appears to "work" doesn't mean that it does not have bugs.

There are many types of mistakes that you can make, especially when working with memory (pointers, arrays, and the like), that may sometimes silently work anyway, and at other times may completely crash. It's largely arbitrary, based on whatever values happen to be present in memory at the addresses that you are erroneously accessing.

Use a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and/or [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug these sorts of issues.

Comment: tomalak sir i  tried gdb and fine the error                       Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0018d9bd in getc () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 . i want ot ask that there are serveral getc statements in prog is there a wat to know the exact line

Comment: @randy: you should learn how to use your debugger. That is out of the scope of a site like StackOverflow. I suggest a book like http://www.amazon.com/Debugging-GDB-GNU-Source-Level-Debugger/dp/1882114884

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible for a program to work for a period of time and then fail.

Have you tried [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific enough to answer without more details.  However, the best thing for you to do would be to use a debugger to run your program in so you can examine what it's doing when it dies, a problem occurs, or to just help you walk through it.  [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is a popular free debugger.

Comment: thanks alot sir for your concern i will surly give it  a try and will ask u if need any help regarding GDB  can I ?